# How to correctly show matplotlib plot in Dash layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-dash

I have the following dummy data.  In this script, I plot the radial chart with matplotlib. Here is the matplotlib code for radial chart: :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create the dummy data
hour_timetable = [i for i in range(24)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-01 23:59:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 2) for n in range(72)]})
df['HOUR'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour
df['MINUTE'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute
df['DBP'] = np.random.uniform(50, 80, size=72)
df['DBP2'] = np.random.uniform(45, 75, size=72)
df['SBP'] = np.random.uniform(110, 180, size=72)
df['SBP2'] = np.random.uniform(90, 130, size=72)
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
df = df[(df.ID==1)]

df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'])
df['seconds'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour*60+df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute

# Compute areas and colors
hour_minute = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24*60, endpoint=False)

# print(len(hour_minute))
r = df.SBP.tolist()
r2 = df.SBP2.tolist()
s = df.DBP.tolist()
s2 = df.DBP2.tolist()
theta = df.SBP # power = SBP
area = r
colors = r

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})

ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], r, color='red', label='SBP') # markers are controlled with 'o-'
ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], r2, color='red', label='SBP2')

ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], s, color='blue', label='DBP') # markers are controlled with 'o-'
ax.plot(hour_minute[df['seconds']], s2, color='blue', label='DBP2')

ax.fill_between(hour_minute[df['seconds']], r, r2, interpolate=True, color='red', alpha=0.3)
ax.fill_between(hour_minute[df['seconds']], s, s2, interpolate=True, color='blue', alpha=0.3)

# clock labels
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(24))
ax.legend(loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.1), fontsize=8)

# make the labels go clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 180)

# place 0 at the top
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2.0)

plt.show()
```

I would like to integrate radial chart code given above, in the following layout in Single Inspection Part. Basically, I want to substitue scatter plot with radial chart. Here is the code for Dash layout:

```py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, dash_table
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import os, dash, random
import numpy as np

hour_timetable = [i for i in range(24)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-01 23:59:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 2) for n in range(72)]})
df['HOUR'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour
df['MINUTE'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute
df['DBP'] = np.random.uniform(50, 80, size=72)
df['DBP2'] = np.random.uniform(45, 75, size=72)
df['SBP'] = np.random.uniform(110, 180, size=72)
df['SBP2'] = np.random.uniform(90, 130, size=72)
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time

df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'])
df['seconds'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour * 60 + df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute
# Compute areas and colors
hour_minute = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24 * 60, endpoint=False)

app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Container(
        [
            html.Br(),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown', options=df.ID.unique(), value=df.columns[0]),
            html.Br(),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H2('Single inspection graph'),
                        dcc.Graph(id='single_inspection', style={'height': '80vh'})
                    ],
                    width=3,
                ),
                dbc.Col([
                    html.H2('Line plot'),
                    dcc.Graph(id='line_plot', style={'height': '36vh'}),
                    html.H2('Data table'),
                    html.Div(id='data_table_container', style={'height': '36vh', 'overflow': 'scroll'})
                ], width=5),
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H2('Multi inspection graph'),
                        dcc.Graph(id='multi_inspection', style={'height': '80vh'})
                    ],
                    width=4,
                    style={'height': '100%'},
                )
            ], className='vh-100', justify='start')
        ],
        style={
            "background-color": "green",
            "padding": "0 1rem 0 1rem",
            "margin-left": "0",
            "margin-right": "0",
        },
        fluid=True
    )
],
)


@app.callback(
    Output('single_inspection', 'figure'),
    Output('line_plot', 'figure'),
    Output('multi_inspection', 'figure'),
    Output('data_table_container', 'children'),
    Input('dropdown', 'value'),
)

def first_callback(dropdown):
    single = px.scatter(df[df.ID==dropdown], x="TIME", y=["SBP", "DBP"])
    line = px.line(df[df.ID==dropdown], x="TIME", y=["SBP", "DBP"],
                         facet_col_wrap=2,
                         facet_row_spacing=0.1,
                         facet_col_spacing=0.09)
    multi = px.line(df[df.ID==dropdown], x="TIME", y=["SBP", "DBP"])
    table =  dash_table.DataTable(
                id='datatable-advanced-filtering',
                columns=[
                    {'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True} for i in df[df.ID==dropdown].columns
                    # omit the id column
                    if i != 'id'
                ],
                data=df[df.ID==dropdown].to_dict('records'),
                editable=True,
                page_action='native',
                page_size=10,
                filter_action="native"
            )

    return single, line, multi, table


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I attempted the following code, but I only see a broken image icon. Here is my attempt:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import io
import base64

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, dash_table
import plotly.express as px

hour_timetable = [i for i in range(24)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-01 23:59:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 2) for n in range(72)]})
df['HOUR'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour
df['MINUTE'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute
df['DBP'] = np.random.uniform(50, 80, size=72)
df['DBP2'] = np.random.uniform(45, 75, size=72)
df['SBP'] = np.random.uniform(110, 180, size=72)
df['SBP2'] = np.random.uniform(90, 130, size=72)
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time

df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'])
df['seconds'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour * 60 + df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute
# Compute areas and colors
hour_minute = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24 * 60, endpoint=False)

app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Container(
        [
            html.Br(),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown', options=[{'label': str(i), 'value': i} for i in df['ID'].unique()],
                         value=df['ID'].unique()[0]),
            html.Br(),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H2('Single inspection graph'),
                        html.Div(id='single_inspection', style={'height': '80vh'})
                    ],
                    width=3,
                ),
                dbc.Col([
                    html.H2('Line plot'),
                    dcc.Graph(id='line_plot', style={'height': '36vh'}),
                    html.H2('Data table'),
                    html.Div(id='data_table_container', style={'height': '36vh', 'overflow': 'scroll'})
                ], width=5),
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H2('Multi inspection graph'),
                        dcc.Graph(id='multi_inspection', style={'height': '80vh'})
                    ],
                    width=4,
                    style={'height': '100%'},
                )
            ], className='vh-100', justify='start')
        ],
        style={
            "background-color": "green",
            "padding": "0 1rem 0 1rem",
            "margin-left": "0",
            "margin-right": "0",
        },
        fluid=True
    )
],
)


@app.callback(
    Output('single_inspection', 'children'),
    Output('line_plot', 'figure'),
    Output('multi_inspection', 'figure'),
    Output('data_table_container', 'children'),
    Input('dropdown', 'value'),
)
def first_callback(dropdown):
    df_selected = df[df.ID==dropdown]

    # Create the radial chart
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df_selected['seconds']], df_selected['SBP'], color='red', label='SBP')
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df_selected['seconds']], df_selected['SBP2'], color='red', label='SBP2')
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df_selected['seconds']], df_selected['DBP'], color='blue', label='DBP')
    ax.plot(hour_minute[df_selected['seconds']], df_selected['DBP2'], color='blue', label='DBP2')
    ax.fill_between(hour_minute[df_selected['seconds']], df_selected['SBP'], df_selected['SBP2'],
                    interpolate=True, color='red', alpha=0.3)
    ax.fill_between(hour_minute[df_selected['seconds']], df_selected['DBP'], df_selected['DBP2'],
                    interpolate=True, color='blue', alpha=0.3)
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
    ax.set_xticklabels(range(24))
    ax.legend(loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.1), fontsize=8)
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 180)
    ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2.0)

    # Convert the plot to an image
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png', dpi=150)
    buf.seek(0)
    image = Image.open(buf)
    encoded_image = base64.b64encode(buf.read()).decode('utf-8')

    # Generate the components to display the image
    img_html = html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image),
                        style={'height': '80vh', 'width': '100%'})

    # Create the Line Plot
    line_plot = px.line(df_selected, x="TIME", y=["SBP", "DBP"],
                        facet_col_wrap=2,
                        facet_row_spacing=0.1,
                        facet_col_spacing=0.09)

    # Create the Multi Inspection Graph
    multi_inspection = px.line(df_selected, x="TIME", y=["SBP", "DBP"])

    # Create the Data Table
    data_table = dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-advanced-filtering',
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True} for i in df_selected.columns if i != 'id'],
        data=df_selected.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        page_action='native',
        page_size=10,
        filter_action="native"
    )

    return img_html, line_plot, multi_inspection, data_table


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

How can I fix my code so that it shows the radial chart? I appreciate any help or hint. I there are alternatives, I am also open to know.